# RDP add domain users broken

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain, domain-controller, rdp, ping

I have 3 Windows Server 2008 R2 instances, all of which are virtual machines hosted on a single VMware ESX server:

- Domain controller with DNS services
- DHCP/RRAS
- File server

All three servers are configured with static IPv4 addresses. All servers are in the same domain, `SOFTWARE`. RDP is enabled on all 3 servers.

I can connect to the DHCP/RRAS server via RDP, but I cannot connect to the domain controller or the file server.

When I add RDP users to the File server (both are domain admins for testing), they show up like this:

[image: Screenshot of Remote Desktop Users dialog box. Test User 1 and Test User 2 are on the list. Question marks appear over their user icons, indicating a potential problem.]

What is happening? Why don't I even get a login screen for RDP on the domain controller?

Comment: Is the service started and allowed in the local firewall?

Comment: @chutz yes, the service starts when you click the 3rd radio button and exception to the firewall is made. I've tried shutting firewall down - but that doesn't make a difference as it's an exception already.

Comment: What OS are you connecting *from* and what is the exact error message that you get when it fails? Do *all* of your servers point to your AD DNS server and **only** your AD DNS server?

Comment: are all of these machines members of the domain? and are you logging in with a local account or a domain account?

Comment: @MDMarra all servers point to the AD/DNS DNS from the intern adapter. The external adapter points to the internet.

This system is working for 1 PC (the active directory domain controller). I can login via RDP on that one. The other 2 servers refuse to login with the domain credentials.

Comment: @longneck I'm loggin in with domain account and domain account only. No local accounts.

Comment: @Robuust : Local accounts on domain controllers are part of domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already said in [Bernie White's answer comments](https://serverfault.com/questions/442586/rdp-add-domain-users-broken#comment489849_444209), but just to make it clearer for newcomers:

Execute:

```
C:\Windows\System32\sysprep\sysprep.exe /generalize /oobe /reboot
```

Then rebind to the domain and reboot.

Answer (score 3):

## Update

In this case the answer was point 5. But the other points are here for others who might have similar questions.

### Account Resolution

From your screen shot the user icons with the question mark indicate that the SIDs for the user accounts can not be resolved, which is fundamental. This could either be that the user accounts have been deleted from your Active Directory or there is a connectivity problem between the file server and your domain controller. Based on that you are having other issues I will assume the account do still existing in Active Directory.

To resolve this I would go back to the basics. Check the following:

**1. DNS Resolution**

Can you resolve you domain controller (DC) by DNS name.

i.e. Run > Cmd.exe and use nslookup .

e.g. `nslookup server1.consoto.com`

If you can’t resolve check that local network settings are point to the DC as the DNS server and that there is nothing between the two servers like Windows firewalls or devices that would prevent this type of connectivity. Also check that you can resolve DNS on the DC itself.

**2. Time in Sync**

Is the local time and time zones on both the DC and file server synchronised. They should be ideally exactly the same, and the file server should be getting it’s time off the DC. The following can help resolve this:

```
   w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier
   w32tm /resync /rediscover
   net stop w32time
   net start w32time
```

When running Windows domain connected servers as VMs on ESX, disable host time sync for all VMs. This is done ether by:

1. editing the `.vmx` file directly by browsing the datastore from the command-line or downloading the file from the datastore making the changes and uploading the file again.
2. using `Configuration Parameters` option from the VM's settings in the vSphere or VI client to Add a row.

See http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1189 for more information.

Also it is also good practise to:

1. Configure an external time source for you Windows DC. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816042
2. Configure youyr ESX/vSphere hosts to get time from the DC. See http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1035833

**3. Check Event Logs**

There would most likely be a lot of errors and warnings logged in the event log.

**4. Re-establish Trust**

If all else fails you can re-establish the trust between the file server and the DC be disconnecting it from the domain, rebooting and rejoining it again.

Don’t do this though if you have outstading time or DNS issues.

**5. VM might have duplicate SIDs with another**

When you build a Windows VM from a template in VMware vCenter you can choose to "customise" it. This reseals the operating system with sysprep when it starts for the first time after it is deployed from a template. Resealing an operating system when cloning or deployment templates is important because each Windows install has unique information such as security identifiers (SIDs) that is uses when connected to a domain. These can't be duplicated on another VM.

To read more about customisation in VMware vCenter see [Sysprep file locations and versions](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1005593).

If you don't have this option you can do it manually by using sysprep and using the generalize option, which will remove the computer SID and put the computer into the welcome wizard. Sysprep can be found `C:\Windows\System32\sysprep\sysprep.exe`

As a note, don't generalise your base template, because you can only do it 3 times and most people want to apply updates to their template on a monthly basis.

### RDP to DC

It’s hard to say exactly without more information, like event logs (may be you can post some error event IDs). But I would suggest that you check the file server issue first because it may be indicative of another issue. When the file server is working try to RDP from the file server to the DC.

I would also check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794832(v=ws.10).aspx if you are attempting to connect to the DC using an older RDP client or operating system.

If that doesn’t help please provide more information like where you are trying to connect from (is it across a RAS connection?) so we can help.

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you are running the server as a VM on ESX, disable host time sync for all VMs. See http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1189

I cannot see those .vmx files. Only deployed templates.

Comment: Use the step that indicates how to set a Configuration Parameter by adding a new row. The VM must be powered off. The article refers to the Virtual Infrastructure client but it is the same for new vSphere clients too.

Comment: This helped me, but did not solve my issue unfortunately. Sorry for the very late reply.

Comment: Where are you stuck at?

Comment: I ran everything, but I'm still unable to RDP to the other servers. It keep showing my RDP using as broken users.

Comment: If you disconnected and rejoined the domain. The VM may have the same hardware id. Were they cloned from the same source template/vm? If so was a sysprep reseal done?

Comment: maybe very late. But indeed they messed up because of this.